# How can I show the result of a mysql query with filters in node js and handlebars

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, handlebars.js

I have the following code for the query

```
router.get('/a', isLoggedIn, async(req,res)=>{
    const data = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM supporting_documents ORDER BY date desc')
    const report = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM report_weekly ORDER BY semana asc ')
    res.render('math/a', {data,report})
})

 .hbs

        <h2>Monto:{{#each mes}}
            {{else}}
            No hay montos
            {{/each}}</h2>
```

How could I show the result? In the console.log it shows me the result of the sum, how could I show that result with handlebars?

Answer (score 0):

If you can pass the json of the `data` and `report` objects it is easier to help you show how to output this.

For example, if the data would be an array of items:

```
[
  [ 'column a', [ 'column b' ] ],
  [ 'column a', [ 'column b' ] ],
]
```

You could iterate the data something like this:

```
<table>
  {{#each data}}
    <tr>
      {{#each this}}
        <td>{{this}}</td>
      {{/each}}
    </tr>
  {{/each}}
</table>
```

What you are looking for is the [each](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#each) built in helper.

I made an example of [how to render an array in handlebars in codepen](https://codepen.io/ddikman/pen/wvmYvGE) for you as well.